# How to turn off email verification in Liferay from command line or database edit?

Tags: liferay, email-validation

I was not using email verification in Liferay. When I turned it on, then first thing it did is ask email verification code FROM ME. So it did suicide, since I have no access to Liferay anymore.

How to fix it?

**SOLUTION**

I have updated `Users_` table with SQL query. It has a field saying whether email was verified, I said `1`.

Comment: you check this link https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/8594659 hope it may help you

Comment: @dims Can you please give the Solution as an answer and then accept it. So that your question is marked as answered and won't appear in the uanswered list and may help a few dozen people out there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay database has `User_` table, which has `emailAddressVerified` field. While verification was turned off, the values in this field was zeros but were not affecting anything. When I turned it on, zeros start to play their role -- saying that many users are unverified, preventing these users to log in. Even administrators (not sure about main administrator).

So, to mark some user as verified, one should execute a query:

```
update User_ set emailAddressVerified=1 where screenName='username';
```

After that a user can enter control panel and change mail verification off or perform some other modifications.